trouble with fscanf in funtion
I can't get this function to work properly. It crashes at the for loop. I post only the excerpt and the variables.
I tried changing the hurricanes[i] and states[i] to &hurricanes[i] and &states[i]. The program runs but saves only the starting letter intot the arrays.
Here is an exerpt of the file that is read.
2005 Katrina LA

int years[NUM_HURRICANES] = {0};

    char    hurricanes[NUM_HURRICANES][100] = {0},
            states[NUM_HURRICANES][5] = {0};

void file_handling(int *years, char *hurricanes, char *states)
{
    //File handling
    FILE *file_ptr;

    //accesing the file
    if ((file_ptr = fopen("hurricanes.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        puts("File not found.");
    else
        puts("File found.");

    //load the data into the arrays
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_HURRICANES; i++)
        fscanf(file_ptr, "%d %s %s", &years[i], hurricanes[i], states[i]);

    fclose(file_ptr);
}


Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

And if you fail to open the file, you should probably not continue to attempt to read from the file. And what happens if there are not NUM_HURRICANES records in the file? Also, you should always check what any scanf family function returns.

How do you call that function? You want to read strings into hurricanes[i] and states[i] but these are only single characters: char *hurricanes, char *states. These have different types than the global arrays you define.

The parameters should be char hurricanes[][100], char states[][5] if you're passing the entire arrays as arguments.

Instead of multiple arrays for the information about a hurricane, consider a structure to organize the information.
Scanning using %s can easily write too many characters to the storage array. Defining a length and stringifing allows inclusion of the number of characters to scan into the format string.
A successful scan will return 3.
There will be problems if the data contains states similar to New York or Florida. One contains whitespace that will cause the next scan to fail. The second will be truncated to Flor and the pending ida will cause the next scan to fail.
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_HURRICANES 1000
#define LEN_NAME 99
#define LEN_STATE 4
// stringify to use in format string
#define FS(x) SFS(x)
#define SFS(x) #x

typedef struct hurricane_s {
    int year;
    char name[LEN_NAME + 1]; // +1 for terminating zero
    char state[LEN_STATE + 1];
} hurricane_t;

void file_handling ( hurricane_t *hurricanes) {
    FILE *file_ptr = NULL;

    if ( NULL != ( file_ptr = fopen ( "hurricanes.txt", "r"))) {
        //load the data into the arrays
        for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_HURRICANES; i++) {
            if ( 3 != fscanf ( file_ptr, "%d %"FS(LEN_NAME)"s %"FS(LEN_STATE)"s"
            , &hurricanes[i].year
            , hurricanes[i].name
            , hurricanes[i].state)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(file_ptr);
    }
    else {
        perror ( "hurricane.txt");
    }

}

int main ( void) {
    hurricane_t hurricanes[NUM_HURRICANES] = {0};

    file_handling ( hurricanes);
    int loop = 0;
    while ( loop < NUM_HURRICANES && 0 != hurricanes[loop].year) {
        printf ( "years %d name %s state %s\n"
        , hurricanes[loop].year
        , hurricanes[loop].name
        , hurricanes[loop].state);
        ++loop;
    }
    return 0;
}


You have global variables. You do not need to pass them as function arguments to access them. That's the whole point of the having global variable. To change a variable inside another function(out of the scope of the variable) you need to pass it by reference. It is the same case for scanf. int* ptr = &num; Here ptr is reference to variable num. This reference points to the memory location of num. For year you need to pass a reference when something is already pointer like char a[40]; you can pass the pointer directly. for example to store the reference  you can do char *b = a;
Here is how can structure you code with global variables:
FILE: hurricane.txt
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA

FILE: main.c
#define NUM_HURRICANES 10
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int years[NUM_HURRICANES] = {0};
static char hurricanes[NUM_HURRICANES][100] = {0}; 
static char states[NUM_HURRICANES][5] = {0};

void file_handling(void) {
    
    FILE *file_ptr;

    if ((file_ptr = fopen("hurricanes.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        puts("File not found.");
        exit(1);
    } else puts("File found.");

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_HURRICANES; i++) {
        fscanf(file_ptr, "%d %s %s", &years[i], hurricanes[i], states[i]);
        printf("%d %s %s\n", years[i], hurricanes[i], states[i]);
    }

    fclose(file_ptr);
}

int main(void) {
    file_handling();
    return 0;
}

std output:
File found.
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA
2005 Katrina LA


I cant say why your code crashes. because u clearly are not sharing what causes the crash.
